# For the first time I click on a cell, it is taking some time to load the next view controller. Why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, xib

I'm initializing the view controller in the didSelectRowAtIndexpath method, as follows,

```
GuideViewController *gViewController = [[GuideViewController alloc] initWithGuideline:obj withTitle:@"" htmlFilePath:@""];
```

and then pushing it using the navigation controller as follows,

```
[[self.parent navigationController] pushViewController:gViewController animated:YES];
```

This is taking some 3 seconds to load for the very first time I install it in the device, but from the next time onwards its smooth and fast. I'm wondering how its working fast from the next time I select the cell.
Please suggest some ideas to fix this issue.
FYI: The project is Non-ARC.

Comment: Without seeing the code for GuideViewController even Yoda help you here cannot.

Comment: What is `self.parent ? And what are you doing in the GuideViewController viewDidLoad/viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear ?

Comment: What is 'initWithGuideline' ? Is it some concept I am not aware of ?

Comment: Set some timers. E.g. `NSLog (@"%@", [NSDate date]);` or so at the beginning and the end of all your methods that are executed upon loading the view and find out, where exactly it takes that much time. Then we go from there.

Comment: remove `[self performSelector:@selector(call:) withObject:self afterDelay:3.0 ];
` from ViewDidLoad. without source code this is what i can guess.

Comment: If you are performing any time taking task in viewDidLoad Write that code in viewDidAppear..

Comment: @Bunty Madan nice guess :)))))

Comment: @danypata i had no way

Comment: @utsabiem : "initWithGuideline' is just a custom init method I wrote to intialize few variables of that class.

Comment: Are you initialising and loading UIWebview in the init method or viewDidLoad method?

Answer (score 1):

I have developed an app with a UITabBarController.

And I also wanted my app to be fast. Because some tab were loooooong to load, I've preloaded them by doing :

```
ViewControllerToPreload.view
```

Indeed, calling view will call the viewDidLoad method of your UIViewController : ViewControllerToPreload.
You can make this call in the viewDidAppear: method of your current view controller, so it will load your next view controller, which will be faster to appear when called.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you profile with Instruments and you will find the answer as to what is happening during those 3 seconds.